# Submit form on press of specific key

Tags: javascript

Is there any way how to submit form when you press some predefined key on your keyboard (for example ; key)? I was thinking about something with onkeypress, but dont know how to set it just for one specific key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and you were right with thinking `onkeypress`, just pass in the `event`, and check which key is pressed with `event.which`:

```
function keyPressed(event) {
    if (event.which == 186) //keycode for semi-colon
        console.log("Semi-colon pressed!");
    }
}
```

Now just attach this function to a keypress handler.

Edit: Got the keycodes from here: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to get the keycode and submit the form if it's the right keycode.

To get the keycode from an event, do:

```
$(document).on("keypress", function(event) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    var keyWhich = event.which;
    if(keyCode = 'yourkey' || keyWhich = 'yourkey') {
        $(form).submit();
    }
});
```

For a full list of keycodes to replace 'yourkey' with, I'd recommend something like [this cheat sheet](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes). Just type your key in the input and use whatever value it provides as your function's logic

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 186) { // ; key
           $('#theform').submit();
        }
    });

});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nevster/KULXq/3/).